# How do I get this linearlayout working on android?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to create a scrollview that contains a linearlayout with some options inside of it. I'd like for the options to show up at the top and grow downwards, and to have "save," "delete," and "cancel" buttons which show up at the very bottom of the screen (if there is space left in between the bottom of all the options and the top of the buttons).

Here's a screenshot of my attempt:
http: //img375.imageshack.us/img375/3628/10370572.png
(StackOverflow was only letting me post a single link so you'll have to get rid of the space in between http: and the rest)

As you can see, the buttons show up directly below the options rather than at the bottom of the screen. In fact the top level (green) linearlayout doesn't even extend all the way down, despite having a height of fill_parent and a weight of 1 (and the blue is the scrollview, so there is room to expand).

I've tried every possible combination of heights, weights, gravities, and anything else to get this working and still can't do it. Everytime I pasted my xml layout into here, the top and bottom portions got cut off, so instead I pasted it here: [pastey link](http://www.pastey.net/137504-36x1)

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that, you change the "Layout height" of the green portion of your linear layout to "fill_parent".

Add the Buttons Linear layout to with "Wrap_content".

If you paste your XML it would be simpler to identify.

-Vinay

Comment: The green linear layout _does_ have a height of fill_parent, I said that in my post. The XML is also linked in my post.